# What is the appropriate use case in a REST API to use the ? Question Mark for parameters?

Tags: api, rest, structure

On [this](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html) REST tutorial site,

When, if ever, is it appropriate to put something like

```
http://dev.m.gatech.edu/developer/USER_NAME/api/WIDGET_NAME/test?query=someparam
```

instead of

```
http://dev.m.gatech.edu/developer/USER_NAME/api/WIDGET_NAME/test/someparam
```

or

```
http://dev.m.gatech.edu/developer/USER_NAME/api/WIDGET_NAME/test/someparam/var1/param/var2/param
```

?

I've seen various things on SO.

Comment: All cases where you are performing a GET request and need to pass some parameters should be in the form of `?param=value`

Comment: What is the whole deal with the folks that say use all the slashes and no question mark?

Comment: So is that first link up top, they are just wrong?  Man, who can you trust these days :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All cases where you are performing a GET request and need to pass some parameters should be in the form of ?param=value.

> So is that first link up top, they are just wrong? Man, who can you trust these days :).

No, they are not wrong. Take this example from that site

```
GET http://www.example.com/customers/33245/orders
```

Here, `customers`, `33245` and `orders` are not query parameters, they are resource endpoints, or *uri nodes* as they call them on your restapitutorial.com

If you do

`GET http://www.example.com/customers` you get all customers
`GET http://www.example.com/customers/33245` you get customer 33245
`GET http://www.example.com/customers/33245/orders` you get customer 33245's orders

They all return 0 or more resources. If you were to apply a query to for example the first one and you wanted to GET all customers with *John* as first name, you would do this

```
GET http://www.example.com/customers?firstname=John
```

In the last example in your question, it would be written as `GET http://www.example.com/customers/firstname/john` instead, which is **wrong** in terms of restfulness. There is no customer resource 'firstname', and there is no firstname resource 'john'.

There are customers whose firstname is 'john' and you would GET them with

```
GET http://www.example.com/customers?firstname=John
```

Comment: @johnny no, they mean an url that you can make requests to (GET, POST etc.)

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe It should be called the Direct Object.  It is receiving the action of the verb.

Comment: @TimCastelijns what do you mean by **There is no customer resource 'firstname'**. Can you elaborate on how to see what is a resource and what is not?

Comment: @SahilBabbar a resource is a standalone entity. `User` is a resource.`Car` is a resource, `Company` is a resource. `firstName` is not, `leftRearWheel` is not, etc

Comment: @TimCastelijns so using `customers?firstname=John` approach is the dedicated endpoint being made available, especially with requests that will be used a lot. Both the URLs serve the same data but one is correct according to REST design principles and one is not, although, it serves the same functionality. Right?

Comment: @SahilBabbar I guess, although the functionality depends on the implementation